# Does exponential precalculation contradict polynomial-time reduction?

Tags: complexity-theory, transformation

Suppose I have a problem A that has at least one yes and one no instance which may take exponentially long to find.

In Problem B we get 2 instances of A and are supposed to decide whether or not 1 of them is a yes instance and one of them is a no instance

Assuming we know one "No" instance of A we can create an instance of B by giving (I,"No-Instance") where I is an arbitrary input for A which we want to decide. (Effectively transforming every instance of A into a B instance in O(1))
In this case, if I is a "Yes" instance , the instance of B will also be a "Yes" instance (same for "no")

Now, to find this No instance that we're going to use for every transformation we may need exponential time once.
Does this factor into the transformation's runtime? Aka. is it still a polynomial-time transformation then?

Comment: It's not exactly clear whether the pre-calculation can be done once and for all without knowing the input, and will be usable for all possible inputs. If so, it does not count as part of the algorithm's running time any more than you would count the time it took the programmer to write the algorithm in the first place.

Comment: The precalculation is once only. Since we need to find exactly one No instance only (aka one specific Input that will be answered with "no" by Problem A). That specific instance will then be reused to create instances of B. The Input we're getting afterwards for A (which we want to transform to an instance of B) does not matter since our no instance will still be a no instance

Comment: In that case, yes, the algorithm which transforms `x -> (x, c)` for a fixed constant `c` is indeed constant-time, regardless of how long it took you to compute `c` in the first place, since computing `c` is not part of the algorithm which does the transformation.

Comment: That was pretty much exactly my reasoning as well, just needed someone to confirm this actually makes sense. Thanks!